# Software for accessing Google Drive Whatsapp Backup?

Tags: google-drive, whatsapp

I use whatsapp on my desktop (not just my smartphone).

I'm interested in software(other than whatsapp!) for accessing Google Drive  Whatsapp Backup

It seems that Google Drive offers no option that  I can see, for accessing the whatsapp backup file.  (Maybe possible with some API). They list it https://drive.google.com/drive/backups  but give no download option.   Hence I am looking for a software solution.

There is some software - desktop software , software that can run on Windows, that claims to be able to access it , called Elcomsoft Explorer https://www.elcomsoft.com/exwa.html

But it doesn't work for me at the moment, and emailing them they said there's an issue that  they predict will take them 1-3 months for them to resolve.

So i'm looking for other options, to download and preferably also, read, a whatsapp backup file from google drive.

I have tagged this question as Google Drive, as it is an issue with Google Drive.